# Best set of points by which to discretize a Probability Distribution Function

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I need to discretize a Probability Distribution Function (PDF). As soon as I discretize it, its moments change, in general, and that is a problem I would like to control.

Concretely: take the Standard Normal distribution, mean=0, variance=1. Say I would like to discretize it with 3 values. A fair choice would be to take the 2 quartiles and the median. Therefore my discretized Normal distribution is just the following ensemble of points: [-0.6744897501960817, 0.0, 0.6744897501960817] .
Besides being a fair choice, it also leaves the expected value unchanged: 0.
However, the Variance of my discretized PDF is not anymore 1 (!), rather it is about 0.3.
This is obvious from many points of view.

Now the question is: Is there a (fair) set of points so to leave the Variance unchanged? I could take $\pm 1/\sqrt(2)$ and 0, but would it be fair? And what if I decide to use 5 points instead of 3?
More general: Do we have a recommended set of points to use when discretizing a distribution so to leave the n-th moment unchanged (or maybe a few moments unchanged)?

EDIT (some more explanations):

The whole point is maybe clear if I say where I want to get to. I need to use a discretized version of PDF, call it dPDF, in order to: a) evaluate the expected value of some stochastic functions that depend on it, and b) evaluate the Variance of the same stochastic functions that depend on it. Choosing dPDF via quantiles: a) works great, b) works only in asymptotic case, where n is large. Now, what set of points should I best use for b), i.e.for calculating Var[f(X)], where X is norm. distributed, and f is arbitrary?

Comment: How are you calculating the variance and probabilities?

Comment: When you discretize a distribution, you must also specify the probability of selecting each outcome. Sure the variance is 0.3 if you're equally like to chose each of the three outcomes, but you can change those probabilities to keep mean 0 and variance  1.

Comment: @WilliamM.: Variance of [-0.6744897501960817, 0.0, 0.6744897501960817] would just be the average square deviation from the mean: E[(x-mu)^2] where mu, in this case, is just 0. So you get ((-0.67..)^2 + 0 + (+0.67..)^2)/3 $\approx$ 0.3

Comment: @JLinsta: sure, one may, but I would like to have a set of numbers that represent my PDF, just like if you were to randomly sample it.

Comment: Then your discretisation is plain wrong. If you use the same probability to each sample, you are discretising the uniform distribution! You need to set appropiate weights.

Comment: Well, it is asymptotically correct for sure. Say I want to discretize with 1000 points. Then I would similarly break down the x axis into 1001 spaces and extract the 1000 quantiles related to probabilities n/1001, where n = [1, 1000]. 
If you do so, your variance is approx 0.988, quite close to the desired value = 1.

Comment: I see what you are doing. You are gonna select a lot more points around 0 than in the tails. That will also work, but much more slowly than using a uniform mesh and adding weights.

Comment: Perfect, now you understood me. Then: I cannot use mesh and I cannot use weights. The question remains: can you suggest me a valid set of points to use?
I used quantiles since it looked a fair approach, but maybe there are rules/suggestions so as to use a better set of points.

Comment: The most common way to deal with this is to do a uniform mesh and add weights. I wouldn't know how it works for using quantiles. I suspect a $n^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ factor of converge will be around. So if the uniform mesh plus weights converges at $c n^\alpha,$ the quantile version would converge at $c n^{\alpha + \frac{1}{2}},$ where $\alpha$ is some negative coefficient, maybe $\alpha = -1.$

Comment: Sure, thanks. Just I cannot use this stuff. I have some basic restrictions. The whole point is maybe clear if I say where I want to get to. I need to use a discretized version of PDF, call it dPDF, in order to: a) evaluate the expected value of some stochastic functions that depend on it, and b) evaluate the Variance of the same stochastic functions that depend on it. Choosing dPDF via quantiles: a) works great, b) works only in asymptotic case, where n is large. Now, what set of points should I best use for b), i.e.for calculating Var[f(X)], where X is norm. distributed, and f is arbitrary?